# Custom attribute search suggestions

Tags: intershop

We have a requirement to retrieve 3 kinds of search suggestions:

1. Product suggestions
2. Category suggestions
3. Brand suggestions

*Its important to note here that the brand suggestions should come from a custom attribute named `Brand`*.

So far we have tried 2 different approaches, both unsuccessful for different reasons:

### Approach 1 - SF Object Suggest Search

By using the `SF Object Suggest Search` we almost got what we needed. The product and category suggestions are working as expected. The problem lies with the brand suggestions. According to the [documentation](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/28682G) the brand suggestions come from the `ManufacturerName` attribute:

> The brand suggestions are collected from the ManufacturerName index attribute of the SFProductSearch index.

Besides it being a very bad practice from Intershop to name something `Brand` whilst it is actually the `ManufacturerName` our real problem with this is that 
all our products have a custom attribute named `Brand` which specifies the brand, and we use the default `ManufacturerName` field for the actual manufacturer of the product.

What we would like to achieve is that the brand suggestions are collected from the `Brand` index attribute of the `SFProductSearch` index instead of from the `ManufacturerName` index attribute.

The documentation also specifies that one of the downsides of the `SFObjectSuggestSearch` is that it has:

> A limited hard-coded set of supported attributes

This made us believe that it will never be possible to modify the `SFObjectSuggestSearch` in such a way that it behaves in the way we want. So we tried approach 2.

### Approach 2 - SFProduct Search Suggest

By using the `SFProduct Search Suggest` and adding the autosuggest attributes to the `SFProductSearch` product index we are able to retrieve all the attributes we need.

The downside of this approach is however that all `SolrSuggestResultItem` objects that are created have the type of `Unspecified`, which makes it impossible for us to group the products, categories and brands together in a nice way.

The [documentation](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/28682G) on this point is extremely poor/vague as it reads:

> The custom values in the suggest index at search index configuration
>   level can configure custom values with the prefix SuggestType_
>   followed by a type.

So we suspect we have to do something with `SuggestType_` but we can't seem to figure it out. The search index configuration options in the backoffice don't seem to provide anything like it. As a last resort we also tried to make the changes directly into the `ISH-Config.xml` but any changes in these files are overridden every time the search index is build.

### Summary

- Approach 1 is unsuccessful since it suggests manufacturers instead of brands.
- Approach 2 is unsuccessful since the returned `SolrSuggestResultItems` all have a type of `Unspecified`.

Is there any way to get this working with either of these approaches? At this point we don't have a preference for approach 1 or 2, so a solution for either one, or guidance towards a more suitable approach, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question:

After some experimentation we got it to work by making a modification to approach 1.

Inside the `ISH-Config.xml` we changed this:

```
<custom-value name="ObjectSuggestType_brand" type="string">
    <value>ManufacturerName</value>
</custom-value>
```

To this:

```
<custom-value name="ObjectSuggestType_brand" type="string">
    <value>Brand</value>
</custom-value>
```

With this configuration the brand suggestions are now collected from the `Brand` index attribute of the `SFProductSearch` index instead of from the `ManufacturerName` index attribute.

By redeploying the server directly after making this change the configuration won't be overridden when you make changes to the `SF Object Suggest Search` later on.